# What is the best solution to get file paths for a news item from the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables: `news` and `news_files`. The `news` table contains `newsId` and some other columns, `news_files` contains `newsId` and `filePath`. For a `news` record, you can have at least 5 files.

What would be the best solution to retrieve all columns from `news` and all files for this particular `news` record in one single query without duplicates?

I have the following query so far, but for each `news_files` it returns the same `news` records (one row for each `filePath` with same `news`).

```
select n.* from news n 
left outer join news_files nf on n.Id = nf.newsid 
where n.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one to many relationship like `news` to `news_files`, in order to get them all into one query you will, as you have found, need to retrieve duplicate column values from the "one" for each related row in the "many" table.

However, I question the need for wanting to do this in a single query.  For a one to one relationship, if there had been only one `news_files` row per`news` row, it would make sense to attempt to produce them in one query.  But for a one to many, you might as well just query the main table then query the related rows from the "many" relationship table.

```
/* Returns duplicate column values for each news_files row */
/* and all columns from both tables */
SELECT
  n.*,
  nf.*
FROM 
  news n
  LEFT OUTER JOIN news_files nf ON n.Id = nf.newsid
WHERE n.Id = 1
```

You can retrieve *one* column from `news_files` as a comma-separated list using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, however, but this isn't exactly the same as just retrieving all rows. Though MySQL allows columns not appearing in the `GROUP BY` to exist in the `SELECT` list, other RDBMS don't, so for portability the `GROUP_CONCAT()` is placed in a subquery to join against the main table and retrieve all columns.

```
/* Comma-separated list of filePath and all cols from news */
SELECT 
  n.*,
  nf.files
FROM
  news 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT newsid, GROUP_CONCAT(filePath) AS files FROM news_feeds
    GROUP BY newsid
  ) nf ON n.Id = nf.newsid
```

Answer (score 0):

this is assuming you have 2 columns in news and 2 columns in news_files... pad with null however you need them.

```
select n.Id, n.someothercolumn, null as newsId, null as filepath
from news n
where Id = 1

union

select null, null, nf.newsId, nf.filepath
from new_files nf
where newedId = 1

order by isnull(Id, newsId)
```

Not the most elegant but should work if you need something quick and dirty!